# Partially build Unity3D editor extensions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

tl;dr: I need to make Unity compile my extension although compiler errors in other, non-Editor scripts exist.

I made a code generation extension for Unity3D.
When depending on generated code without previously having these dependencies generated via the extension the compiler rightfully throws an error that some references are not found.

To fix the issue you would simply have to generate the code and all references will automatically be resolvable. However, because there are compilation issues, the extension itself is not built and as a result, is not generating the necessary files and thus leaving the system in a deadlock.

I tried to move my extension into `Plugins/Editor/*` to meet the [multi-phase compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html) requirements, however, it seems as if Unity does not honor the new folder structure and won't compile my extension and thus won't generate the necessary code.

Is there any workaround for this specific problem?

Comment: You could temporarily remove/comment out all code with compile errors until the Editor scripts are compiled, generate the missing code. Than uncomment/insert your uncompilable code again.

Comment: That's infeasible for larger projects

Comment: Hm maybe but you asked for a workaround and that is one. Simply go to your projects Asset folder in the systems file browser and cut&paste any folder out of the project that fails to compile, let Unity compile the editor stuff and put your folders back in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to address the problem.

Move your code into a separate DLL and import it into a special folder such as `Plugins/Editor`.

Restart Unity. Restarting is important as Unity only seems to pick-up new plugins at start-up if compilation errors exist.